# How do I choose hotel check-in and check-out dates?

Tags: bookings, hotels

My plane lands the 20th July at 17:35 (5:35 PM).
My plane takes off the 28th July at 13:50 (1:50 PM)

Check in at the hotel is 15:00 (3 PM).
Check out is 12:00 (12 PM)

Do I book from

1. 20 July to 27 July ?
2. 20 July to 28 July ?

I believe it's option 1. But someone told me that since I leave the 28th (check out at that date), I have to book from 20th July to 28th July. Which is right?

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear: if you check in on the 20th and check out on the 21st, you only pay for one night: the 20th. So if you check in on the 20th and check out on the 28th, you only pay for eight nights -- 20th, 21st,..., 26th, 27th. Count it on your fingers!

Comment: Vote to close as this is not about travel, but elementary school (clock/calendar) arithmetic questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after five answers all explaining the same thing the OP is still posting comments about their ‘confusion’. Enough is enough

Comment: Just to make sure: is any of your flights a long distance flight which is either a red eye (overnight) or crossing the international date line (transpacific)? In which case you may have the actual flight dates wrong.

Answer (score 13):

As others have said, there’s absolutely no doubt about it: you want to get your room some time on the 20th (the day you arrive) and want to keep your room until some time on the 28th (the day you leave). So check-in date is the 20th and check-out date is the 28th.

That’s 8 nights:

1. night of the 20th to the 21st
2. night of the 21st to the 22nd
3. night of the 22nd to the 23rd
4. night of the 23rd to the 24th
5. night of the 24th to the 25th
6. night of the 25th to the 26th
7. night of the 26th to the 27th
8. night of the 27th to the 28th

If you book from the 20th to the 27th (7 nights), you have to leave on the 27th before check-out time (12 noon), so you would spending the night from 27th to 28th in the street.

If you were leaving at 1am on the 28th then it would make sense to check out on the 27th because you would need to be at the airport late on the 27th. But this is not the case here.

Check-out date is not the date of the beginning of the last night you spend there (which is indeed the 27th), but the date you actually leave.

Comment: Depending on the location of the hotel, the price of the hotel and the type of flight, if I was leaving at 1am on the 28th, I would be tempted to burn the extra night and check-out say at 10pm.

Comment: This is an image of the calendar of the hotel i want to go : https://imgur.com/a/vMDr1m7

It says 7 nights. This is why I am confused because if I have to leave the 28th at 9 am then the 7th must be the one that span from 27th 3PM to 28th 12 PM.


I don't understand the 8 nights since if I book that way, I don't sleep 8 nights but 7 nights. And the calendar says also that if I choose 20 => 28 it's 8 nights. But why ? I will not sleep 8 nights.

Comment: @adele you WILL sleep 8 nights, you are miscounting

Comment: Last sentence should be at the top of this entire page, +1. *Check-out date is the date you actually leave*, provided it's before 12pm you don't pay anything for it. Booked, yes. Paid for, no.

Comment: @adele I’m not sure why you keep repeating you only need 7 nights. If you arrive on the 20th and leave on the 28th, there are 8 nights in between. I explicitly listed and numbered the nights for this reason, as you can see, there’s 8 nights, not 7. If your goal was to stay only 7 nights, then you need to change your flight dates, either to arrive later, on the 21st, not the 20th, or to leave earlier, on the 27th, not the 28th.

Comment: @adele if you still think you will only sleep 7 nights, please let us know which of the 8 nights listed in the answer you think you won’t be at your hotel.

Answer (score 10):

The correct answer is from July 20 to July 28. Those are the dates you arrive at the hotel (the check-in) and the date you leave (the check out-date). You will leave your room before the checkout our (12P) since you must get to your flight ahead of time. If you had an evening flight, then you could ask for a late checkout (for a fee, subject o availability) or leave the room by noon and spend your time elsewhere. Therefore, the date of your check-out, you will *not* sleep in the hotel.

The best way to understand is to image you had a short one-night trip, arriving on the 20 and leaving on the 21. You would need one hotel night, so checking in on the 20 and checking out on the 21. The hotel would charge you one night, as expected. It would not be possible to book from the 20 to the 20 and sleep the night (there are actually *Day-Room* bookings if you were going to leave in the same afternoon as you arrived).

Comment: on the website, when i book from the 20th to 27th, it says 7 nights which is correct if you count 6 nights up to 27th. then the seventh is the one from 27th 3PM to 28th 12PM (noon). 

If i choose from 20 to 28, it says 8 nights. Which is wrong because my plane is leaving the 28th at 1:50 PM. So i need to leave the room before 12 PM to make it on time. So I don't spend the night of the 28th from 3 PM to 29 th 12 (the 8th night).

Also see my comment on @wonderbear answer.

Comment: @adele Your logic is flawed. The *nights you need a bed to sleep in* are 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27th. Eight nights.

Comment: if you said 20 to 21 that would be one night. Right? 20 to 27 is 7 nights and 20 to 28 is 8 nights. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Because I don't need 8 nights. Because I leave 28th at 09 AM. 

This is an image of the calendar of the hotel i want to go : https://imgur.com/a/vMDr1m7

It says 7 nights. This is why I am confused because if I have to leave the 28th at 9 am then the 7th must be the one that span from 27th 3PM to 28th 12 PM.

Comment: @adele With that calendar shown there, you will check out from the hotel on July 27th in the middle of the day. You will then not have a bed to sleep on between evening July 27 and morning July 28, and your flight is on July 28.

Answer (score 8):

Using your own screenshot I have numbered the nights. You can see you need an 8th night to be able to check out of the hotel on the 28th. Otherwise you'll be checking out on the 27th and have nowhere to sleep that night before your flight on the 28th

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Normally the dates you select are those on which you want to check in and out. You want to check in after your plane lands, that is the 20th of July. You want to check out before your plane departs, that is the 28th of July. I do not quite understand why you believe you should be booking only until the 27th when you clearly want to stay until the 28th.

Comment: I am under the impression that if you book for the 20th, then you can spend the night of the 20th. So from 20th 3 PM to 21th 12 PM.
SInce I land the 20 th at 5:35 PM, I should book from 20th.
Then we arrive at the 27th. I pay for the 27th. Same logic. I paid for the 27th, so i can sleep from 27th 3 PM to 28th 12 PM.
Since my plane leave the 28 th at 1:50 PM : I must leave the hotel at least at 09:50 AM. So why do I need to book for 28th that would let me sleep frop 28 th 3 PM to 29th 12 PM ?

Comment: @adele You can't "book for the 20th" in most hotels. What you do if you want to do the first thing you mention is book from the 20th to the 21st.

Comment: Yes, when I do that, it says 1 night. I understand your point. My mistake. But if you count the nights throught the 27th. it says 7 nights : which is what supposed to be. Why should I book to the 28th ?

Comment: @adele Why do you think it is "supposed to be" 7 nights? Look in a calendar for this year: the 20th of July is a Thursday, the 28th a Friday, so clearly you are staying for one week and one day. I am not really sure how to explain this well.

Comment: This is an image of the calendar of the hotel i want to go : https://imgur.com/a/vMDr1m7

It says 7 nights. This is why I am confused because if I have to leave the 28th at 9 am then the 7th must be the one that span from 27th 3PM to 28th 12 PM.

Comment: @adele in that calendar, you have 8 days selected, 20-27. You check out on the 27, and if you count the nights, it's 7 (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26). If you wanted to check out on the 28 **that would mean one additional day** which is 8 nights in total.  If it helps, look at the calendar and then circle the nights you want to stay in the hotel, then count how many you have circled.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is option 2. You count the nights you want to sleep in the hotel. The check-in/check-out times in this scenario are largely irrelevant.

So arriving 20th July and needing a bed that night through to and including the night of 27th (prior to check out on 28th), you book from 20th to 28th = the nights of 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27th = 8 nights.

Booking option 1 (check-in 20th, check-out 27th) would leave you without a place to sleep on the night of 27th.

Comment: This is an image of the calendar of the hotel i want to go : https://imgur.com/a/vMDr1m7

It says 7 nights. This is why I am confused because if I have to leave the 28th at 9 am then the 7th must be the one that span from 27th 3PM to 28th 12 PM.

Comment: @adele It says 7 nights because you have selected checkin on 20th and checkout on **27th**, which is why no price is shown for that date. The 20th is the 1st night, the 21st, 22, 23, 24, 25, & 26th are the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th & 7th nights respectively. All of the answers are explaining it the same way, it’s hard to understand why you are still confused. Sorry to sound harsh but if you insist on booking checkout on 27th, your confusion will surely be clarified when you find yourself with nowhere to sleep that night.

Comment: While I agree with the conclusion I do not agree at all with the method in this case, which is what is actually the source of the problem. Here the inputs are the check-in and check-out dates and the output is the number of nights, not the other way around. It would be the other way around if OP was making plans: I arrive on the 20th and want to spend 7 nights, when do I leave? The 27th, obviously.

Comment: @jcaron TBH I don’t see why the OP has a problem at all. Given the flight arrival and departure times it’s crystal clear what the check-in/check-out dates should be and how many nights that involves. The only explanation that occurs to me is that the OP thinks booking 7 nights is cheaper than 8 and is looking for a way to achieve that. Or, to be blunt, after 5 answers all saying the same thing in various ways, they are being deliberately obtuse.